# Multiple characters replace in Linux using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a variable in `Linux` like below. This is not a valid variable I just created to test how to replace characters with some new characters.

```
table=123~!@#$%^&*()+|}{:"?><-=[]\;',./
```

Want to replace all the special characters in this table variable like below

```
table1=123_____________________________
```

How can I do that in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same with `tr`

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' _  <file
```

Comment: I am getting a extra `_` after the table. I tried like  `table1=$(echo $table | tr -c '[:alnum:]' _)
`

Comment: `echo` adds a new line, which is converted as well.  You can set `echo -n` to eliminate that.

Comment: TI have changed to `echo -n` but for `$` `*` this doesn't replace the characters For example if my table name is `pd$123` the result I get is `pd` not `pd_123`

Comment: For special chars `bash` interferes, it expands `$123`, most likely not assigned to anything.  You need to single quote the string to hide from `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to `sed` and replace anything that is *not* `^` *alphanumeric* `[:alnum:]` with an *underscore* `_`.

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/_/g'
```

In your code, this would look something like:

```
table1=$(echo table | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/_/g')
```

Comment: Fixed the backslashes.  I've been switching between windows and linux too much the last two days and I'm getting back and forward slash all mixed up. It's a little like hell.

Comment: your command deons't work for `(`, `)`, `$`, `*`, and other characters. For example if my table name is `pd$123` the result I get is `pd` not `pd_123`